# Terraform plan throws Provider Plugin Error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp, azure-rm

I am doing a small POC with terraform and I am unable to run `terraform plan`

My code:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "appngqastorage"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "qa.terraform.tfstate"
    access_key = "my access key here"
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.77"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "qa_resource_group" {
  location = "East US"
  name = "namehere"
}
```

My execution:

1. terraform init = success
2. terraform validate = configuration is valid
3. terraform plan = throws exception

Error:

```
│ Error: Plugin error
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 15, in provider "azurerm":
│   15: provider"azurerm"{
│
│ The plugin returned an unexpected error from plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ConfigureProvider: rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: error while marshaling: string field contains invalid UTF-8
```

Comment: 1) Which version of Terraform and Azure provider? 2) If you did a copy and paste of this code, you have a hidden character or an invalid character. Delete lines 14 and 15 and retype the line manually. Repeat if you get similar errors on other lines.

Comment: Not sure if this will be helpful but this is all typed up by me.

Comment: No, that was not helpful. The details I asked for were not provided. Also, what type of editor are you using? You have a UTF-8 error. Something is wrong with your text file.

Comment: @kkdeveloper7, I ran it with `Terraform v1.0.5 on windows_amd64+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.77.0` it was successful please refer [image](https://i.imgur.com/S0D2jd4.png) with [code](https://i.imgur.com/Q4dtkHi.png)

Comment: @kkdeveloper7,any update ? can you please share which version you are using in terraform and which cmdlt you are using ? powershell/bash?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I am sorry for long reply I was taken away for family matters. So, I tried to remove all code as well as my `main.tf` file and retype everything from start. Same issue. When I run `terraform validate` is runs with out any issues. But as soon as I start running `apply` or `import` I get the same issue. I am wondering if there is something that is cached. 
Just to be complete bullet proof I installed plugin in VSCode and getting same issue. 
I am using CMDER and terraform 1.0.7 and plug in is on 2.77.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little deeper I was able to figure out what was the issue.

Current project I am working on is been utilized within multiple regions. So, when testing work I am swapping my region in order to properly test the data that displays in specific region. This time when running `terraform apply` my windows configuration was pointing to another region not the US.

This [thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vsphere/issues/1267) helped me understand.

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade azure CLI to the latest version using `az upgrade`
2. Log into your azure account using `az login`
3. Re-run your terraform commands!